# Var Dump Not Displaying

Tags: php, mysql, var-dump

Im trying to get the Var Dump to display but all i get is a white screen. Any suggestions?

```
<?php
require('includes/config.inc.php');
require(MYSQL);
$aid = FALSE;
if (isset($_GET['aid']) && filter_var($_GET['aid'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array('min_range' => 0))){
  $aid = $_GET['aid'];

  $q = "SELECT aircraft_id, aircraft_name AS name, aircraft_type AS type, tail_number AS tn FROM aircraft WHERE aircraft_id=$aid";
var_dump($q); die();
}
```

Comment: Common issue - set `error_reporting` to `E_ALL`, so you can find your problem

Comment: Do you define a `MYSQL` constant in your config.inc.php script? Is that config script readable? Either of the requires will kill the script if they fail, and with you undoubtedly having display_errors/error_reporting turned off, you'll never see why. NEVER have those two options turned off while debugging/developing. It's like trying to read a book with your eyes ripped out.

Comment: Why do you think your huge `if` condition is `true`?

Comment: May be your `if` condition is not being executed.

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski I tried that it did not work

Answer (score 1):

Unless `MYSQL` is a defined constant in your script, this line of code will fail and the script execution will stop immediately:

```
require(MYSQL);
```

As explained in the [documentation](http://php.net/require):

> require is identical to include except upon failure it will also produce a fatal E_COMPILE_ERROR level error. In other words, it will halt the script whereas include only emits a warning (E_WARNING) which allows the script to continue.